# Is it possible to have more than one routing in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to ask if it's possible to have more than one routing within `RouteConfig` class. The logic I have is as below, what I want to achieve. I have `actionLink("Dashboard", "Account".....)` already and want to have a unique one that won't conflict with existing one when page is loaded. Please assist me there is a way.

```
namespace ContentManagementSystem  
{  
    public class RouteConfig  
    {  
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)  
        {  
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");  

            routes.MapRoute(  
                name: "Default",  
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // I already have this working fine  

defaults: new { controller = "Dashbaord", action = "_Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional  // I want to have separate, but unique route for this controller for actionResult  

            );  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: If you want to change the `defaults`, just replace the top routes `defaults` with the bottom one that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have more routes you can :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Student",
            url: "students/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Index"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

As shown in the above code, URL pattern for the student route is `students/{id}`, which specifies that any URL that starts with `domainName/students`, must be handled by the `StudentController`.

Notice that we haven't specified {action} in the URL pattern because we want every URL that starts with student should always use Index action of `StudentController`. We have specified default controller and action to handle any URL request which starts from `domainname/students`.

[You can read more here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Add it to top of default route:

```
namespace ContentManagementSystem  
{  
    public class RouteConfig  
    {  
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)  
        {  
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");  

            routes.MapRoute("other_route", "other_route/",
               defaults: new { controller = "OtherController", action = "OtherAction" });

            routes.MapRoute(  
                name: "Default",  
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // I already have this working fine  

defaults: new { controller = "Dashbaord", action = "_Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional  // I want to have seperate, but unique route for this controller for actionResult  

            );  


        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This will not even compile.

Comment: @CodingYoshi which will not even compile? Ignore mine, it was a thought if it was legal or not mate.